# Trying to prove $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2\cos(\theta)+n\theta)d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2\cos(\theta)-n\theta)d\theta$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to prove
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(2\cos\theta)\sin(n\theta)\text{d}\theta=0$$
And after using the prosthaphaeresis formula, I found this equation
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2\cos(\theta)+n\theta)d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2\cos(\theta)-n\theta)d\theta
$$
Mathematica told me that for $n=1,2,3,4,5$, it's true, how to prove it for all integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \; &\sin( 2\cos(\theta) - n \theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&[\theta \mapsto -\theta]  \\
&= \int_{0}^{-2\pi} \; \sin( 2\cos(-\theta) - n (-\theta)) (-1)\,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&[\cos \text{is even}]  \\
&= \int_{0}^{-2\pi} \; \sin( 2\cos(\theta) + n \theta) (-1)\,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&= \int_{-2\pi}^{0} \; \sin( 2\cos(\theta) + n \theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&[\theta \mapsto 2\pi + \theta]  \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \; \sin( 2\cos(2\pi + \theta) + n (2\pi + \theta)) \,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&[\text{$\cos$ and $\sin$ have period $2\pi$.  Requires $n \in \Bbb{Z}$.}]  \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \; \sin( 2\cos(\theta) + n \theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
\end{align*}